# Microsoft Access creating key-value column with formatting (lookup)

Tags: ms-access

I've been looking around but cannot seem to find a simple solution to this. I've got a simple Access database with a few tables, and I'd like to create a new column that contains a value in this format `<REFERENCE ID> - <LETTER>`. The reference ID can be directly extracted from a column (column A in example), but the letter needs to change based on the value of a different column. Is there any way to do this without nested IF conditions? Something like a key-value mapping table where I can specify that the LETTER (in the above format) should be be looked up like this:

Lookup table:

```
|   Key   |Val|
|---------|---|
|  Key 1  | A |
|  Key 2  | B |
|  Key 3  | C |
|  Key 4  | D |
```

Original reference ID table with associated keys:

```
| Reference ID |  Keys |
|--------------|-------|
|     1000     | Key 1 |
|     1001     | Key 3 |
|     1002     | Key 4 |
|     1003     | Key 1 |
|     1004     | Key 2 |
```

New column (the one I'd like to create based off of the answer to the question):

```
|  New column  |
|--------------|
|   1000 - A   |
|   1001 - C   |
|   1002 - D   |
|   1003 - A   |
|   1004 - B   |
```

As you can see, in this case, values are string literals. Keys are picked from a column with data validated fields.

Comment: Where do you want to display the result with formatting then? If you want to update a column then use [UPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/update-statement-microsoft-access-sql) sql statement. [DLookp()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dlookup-function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937) will pick Keys from other table.

Comment: It's not easy to figure out "who is who" among _ReferenceID, Letter, Key, Val,_ and _different column_ and what to look up where.

Comment: I've edited the question so it is easier to orient yourself in @Gustav.

Comment: @Harun24HR the formatted output should be in a new column. The location of which is in the same table as the Reference ID and keys. DLookup() may be what I'd like to use. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a query that pulls in the values.

So,

```
SELECT [Reference ID], [Keys], [Val] FROM FirstTable
LEFT JOIN SecondTable ON SecondTable.Key = FirstTable.Keys
```

So, now use the query in place of the table. It will show all the columns, and pull in and translate the key value out to what you want.